# ScrollTo invalid input in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Is there any way that I can scrollTo first input which have invalid class using VueJs. Right now I am using `window.scrollTo(500, 0);` which is obviously not a proper solution.

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably need to use [Vue.nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) to wait for Vue to apply your invalid class everywhere it needs to be applied.

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
  let domRect = document.querySelector('.error').getBoundingClientRect();
  window.scrollTo(
    domRect.left + document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    domRect.top + document.documentElement.scrollTop
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get first elements with error position:

```
window.scrollTo(document.querySelector('.error').offsetTop, 0);
```

Comment: it scrolls up but not at querySelector  having error class.

Answer (score 0):

One more way :)

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
 document.querySelector('.error').scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"})
});
```